# Paying taxes after Google Play ad revenue

Tags: taxes, online-applications, google, hungary, video-games

I tried Googling everywhere but failed miserably. Could anyone tell me some reliable resources on paying taxes after ad revenue gained from apps uploaded to Google Play?

As far as I know In my region (European Union) it is automatic, but I'm unsure.
To be exact, I live in Hungary, made the game alone, on no budget (started as a hobby, but now that it's finished I might as well make a copper or two).

Comment: It is not likely to be automatic; taxes paid on revenue from Google Ads is similar to any other form of personal revenue - meaning it will be taxed on your income tax return every year. Google may withhold certain amounts of money as an estimate for your annual tax liability, but it is very likely that you will still need to report the income and the tax withholdings on your tax return.

Comment: What you say is true, I asked a tax legal advisor in my country. However, I don't have to be an entrepreneur to get paid - personal taxes are possible.